# Zone File for my own domain on my own server

Tags: ubuntu, bind, dns-zone

I recently aquired a domain from GoDaddy, but find their zone file editing rather bad, since it won't let me do double subdomains, like bb.api.example.com, which are possible, since other web hosts can do that.

I have figured out I need to install BIND on my Ubuntu server - which sounds reasonable to me after reading up on it. How would I configure my domain then to use the zone file that's on my server, and not the one GoDaddy has? I suppose this might have something to do with the domain's nameservers or something.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use your own DNS, you would change your name servers to point to your new server. Using GoDaddy, this involves going into your domain control panel, picking your domain, then going to the name servers section:
[image]

You would then set your nameserver to a URL that points to your server. This could either be a URL on a separate domain, or creating name servers in your own domian.

Answer (score 0):

> but find their zone file editing rather bad, since it won't let me do double subdomains, like bb.api.example.com, which are possible, since other web hosts can do that.

It is possible: [image]

Comment: Huh, quite oddly, when I tried double-subdomains, it did not want to work. It works now though.